# Push other divs to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to slide in a div then move 3 other divs. 
I have fiddle showing how I want to do it. But its not 100% correct.

If you check the fiddle you will see it slides in when you press "Press me". But instead of going over the 3 red divs I want it to push them to the side.

[Fiddle with code](https://jsfiddle.net/j5uykw60/49/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content">

<div class="container" style="position:relative">
<div id="effectMenu"></div>
<div  id="red"><a href="#" id="toggle-menu">Press Me</a></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="red"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#red {
  background-color:red;
  height:50px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  position:relative;
}

#effectMenu
{
    display: none;
    background: grey;
    color: #FFF;
    width:30px;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  width:100px;
}
```

**Script**

```
$(function()
  {
     $("a#toggle-menu").click(function()
                         {
                            $("#effectMenu").animate({width:'toggle'},350);
                            return false;
                         }); 
  });
```

Comment: Not understanding your requirement. Explain it properly please

Comment: Have you seen the fiddle? It pretty much explains it all. Instead of the div sliding in over the 3 red divs. I want it to push away the 3 red divs.

Comment: You are not sliding anything, you are animating the width of div only.

Comment: The animation is still a "slide". But do you understand my question now?

Comment: Nope! I don't know what you want exactly

Comment: If you will not ask properly , you will not get exact answer

Comment: An ID should be unique within a page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the id to a class,toggle a class to the items called left,in the css animate the transition of adding the class using css transitions

```
  <div class="container" style="position:relative">
    <div id="effectMenu"></div>
    <div class="red"><a href="#" id="toggle-menu">Press Me</a></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>

  </div>
</div>
$(function() {
  $("a#toggle-menu").click(function() {
    $("#effectMenu").animate({
      width: 'toggle'
    }, 350);
    $(".red").toggleClass('left');
    return false;
  });
});
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
    transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}

#effectMenu {
  display: none;
  background: grey;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  width: 100px;
}
.left {
  margin-left:30px;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ygmbnwgL/

Answer (score 0):

Using `float` and `relative` position instead of `absolute` one, you can do it :

CSS code :

```
#red {
  background-color:red;
  height:50px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
}

#effectMenu
{
    display: none;
    background: grey;
    color: #FFF;
    width:30px;
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    z-index:1;
    float: left;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  width:150px;
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5uykw60/54/)